# Put date into backup .tar.gz filename

Tags: backup, tar, date, filenames

I'd like to run a simple `tar` command to backup my website directory. It will run through cron, but I want to be able to put the time at which the backup was made as the filename. I don't really mind what format it's in, but something vaguely readable would be good. I'm just looking for a generic command; a way of putting the date in the filename - I can do the rest of the tar stuff.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
tar cfz backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz ...
```

`man strftime` or `man date` to see what `%`-escapes can be used with `date`.

Comment: Thank you :-) I found the date thingy before, but couldn't get it to work for some reason. Geekosaur saves the day!

Comment: This may be specific to which date command variant you use, but this probably does the same thing with a few less characters: tar cfz backup-$(date +%F).tar.gz ...